# ASP.NET with Docker: Proper Way to Build a Path to Internal Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, deployment

I'm facing a challenge in my ASP.NET application running inside a Docker container when it comes to constructing paths to internal files. My code relies on path construction using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and Path.Combine(), and it functions correctly during local docer debugging. However, when deployed to a production Docker environment, I encounter an error like "Could not find a part of the path '/app/Infrastructure/Migrations'."

```cs
public Seeder()
{
    _migrationFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "Infrastructure", "Migrations");

    _seedFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "Infrastructure", "Seed", "data.csv");
}
```

Strangely, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() seems to work as expected when debugging locally but not in production Docker. I've also tried using AppContext.BaseDirectory, but it doesn't work during local debugging.

My project structure includes an Infrastructure folder with two subdirectories, Migrations and Seed, containing the necessary files.

[image]

Could someone provide guidance on the correct way to resolve paths in an ASP.NET application running inside a Docker container? I want to ensure that it works seamlessly both during local dev docker and in the prod docker environment.

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Sparkle.Api/Sparkle.Api.csproj", "Sparkle.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Sparkle.Api/Sparkle.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Sparkle.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Sparkle.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sparkle.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sparkle.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you please share your dockerfile? You can edit the post or include a link to a github gist in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Are these files intended to be baked into the Docker Image, or volumed in to the container?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'm interested in a simpler solution, I thought they were in the volume in the src/Sparkle.Api/Infrastructure/... folder.